# Est-ce que « Important voire crucial » est un pléonasme ?

Tags: sens, synonymes

Est-ce que cette expression est un pléonasme ?

Est-ce que *important* et *crucial* sont de parfaits synonymes ou ont-ils chacun une nuance particulière ?

Est-ce que « crucial » veut dire « plus important que important » ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Au départ *crucial* (du latin crux, crusis --> croix) veut dire : *fait en croix* : incision cruciale.

En philosophie une expérience *cruciale* (au moment où on se trouve à la *croisée* des chemins) permet de confirmer ou de rejeter une hypothèse, elle sert de critère (avec le sens de décisif).

Le sens évoqué dans la question date de 1911, c'est une reprise de l'anglais avec le sens de *fondamental, très important*, synonyme de *capital, critique, déterminant*.

Il y a un autre nuance : « Année, question cruciale. Point crucial » qui ont pour synonyme *délicat* (parce que très difficile à maîtriser).

Alors que *important* est 'seulement' *grand, considérable, grave, principal, sérieux*.
Seul *extrêmement important* se rapproche de *crucial*.

Conclusion :

- « Extrêmement important voire crucial »  est un pléonasme.
- « Important voire crucial », maximise l'attention que l'on donne à *important* et le porte donc un cran au-dessus ; il n'y a donc pas de pléonasme.

---

*<sup>Références extraites du Robert.</sup>*

Comment: Je perçois une nuance entre tout « <insérer un renforcement quelconque> important » et « crucial » : le second qualifie pour moi une condition _sine qua none_, tandis que le premier dit seulement que c'est important. Ensuite, j'imagine qu'il y a toujours une question de perception.

Comment: @Chop - Votre remarque me semble valable si l'on dit seulement « c'est crucial de.. » ou « passer cette étape est crucial » ou encore « c'est important ET crucial  (qui ne sont pas forcément redondants : un travail important dont le résultat est crucial) », il y a en effet une notion de *sine qua none*, dans le sens moderne dérivé de l’anglais (*capital, critique, déterminant*). Mais la question posée inclus le bémol *voire* (par rapport à crucial) : en mettant un dièse sur *important*, on s'arrête au demi-ton, et donc on n'atteint pas "l'absolu" de *crucial*, l'expression du 'ton au-dessus'.

Comment: C'est justement le « voire » qui me conduit à adopter cette définition : « c'est important voire indispensable » serait une substitution qui me semblerait tout aussi valable en l'absence de davantage de contexte.

Comment: @Chop « c'est important *voire* indispensable » est différent de « c'est important *et* indispensable », *voire* induit une incertitude, une réserve, quelque chose de possible, de probable mais qui ne sera pas forcément avéré, d'où l'idée du demi-ton ; quelque chose comme « *voire* plus si affinité » qui laisse une place à l'échec, ou au moins à l'imperfection, il y a un *si* induit ou une condition (ou éventuellement une contrainte) sous-entendu qui empêche le *sine qua non* de s'imposer comme seul condition. « C'est ça ou rien » devient avec *voire* « c'est ça et on risque gros  ».

Comment: Rien à redire sur la définition de « voire ». Je voulais seulement dire que je comprenais « important voire crucial » comme « important voire indispensable ». Le deuxième qualificatif est probable mais pas certain, et il ne cause indubitablement pas de pléonasme avec le premier...

Answer (score 5):

Les médias et la langue courante abusent du mot « crucial » qui en a perdu son sens de base. Comme à un croisement (la croix d'origine), est crucial ce qui oblige à un choix de chemin, à une orientation parfois irréversible. Le synonyme le plus proche est « décisif ».

Il s'agit donc d'un sens différent de « important » ou de ses synonymes, et il n'y a pas de hiérarchie entre eux. Un évènement peut être important sans être décisif, et *vice versa*...